# (Here / There) we go (again)

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

As you are well informed, in English, when it comes to an unpleasant repetitive event, as a protest or showing your disapproval, you can use the structure:

- > [Here we go (again.)](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/here-we-go-again) [Where "again" is optional.]

Now please kindly help me with these questions:

1. I wonder if "there" can be replaced with "here" without any change in meaning.
2. Also, I need to know how can I sarcastically as a sign of surprise and disfavor make an interrogative sentence? I.e. can I say:

   - (There / here) we go again? 
     or
   - (There / here) she goes again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there-you-go) confirms that you can replace **here** with there. Note, though, that the dictionary offers another meaning of **there you go** which is much more widely used:

> used when giving something to someone, usually after a request for the thing, such as giving someone goods that they have bought

2. It's a simple statement- that we are about to embark on the same old nonsense all over again. i don't see that it adds anything to the sentence to make it interrogative, and IMHO it would be confusing to do so.

Comment: Thank you @JavaLatte, but I forgot to ask if we can substitute "**go**" with "**are**" in this sense too.

Comment: @A-friend  You only say **There you are** when you are giving something to somebody, or when you find somebody that you have been looking for.

Comment: Thank you @JavaLatte, but I have heard and read "there you are/go" in another meaning too; used when you think you have proved to someone that what you are telling them is right. However thank you very much.